# SharePoint 2007 WebPart not accessible to any user unless a local user accesses it first

Tags: asp.net, sharepoint, iis

We are facing an issue with a SharePoint webpart we have developed.
After every app pool process recycle, thw webpart is not accessible to any users unless a local user accesses the webpart page first.
We recycle our application pools daily and unless a local user hits the webparty page, it is unavailable for all other users.

The error is : "Pge not Found".
Pointers on what could be causing this would be very helpful.

Kind regards

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We had an identical problem on a project here recently. The problem then was that the anonymous user (guest user) didn't have the rights to load and compile the web part.

Our solution was to give the user that the anonymous visitors requests were run as rights to read the folder where the web part files were stored.

So I suggest you look at the same things. Which user is impersonated when an anonymous user visits your page and what rights does the user have. Most probably he doesn't have the rights needed to compile or setup the web part.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to enable debugging and CallStack for your Web Application to get some more specific information about your error?